# Get the row if Column is having other than provided value in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table_test. I have to get the id if one of the column have value other than the given value.

Table_test

```
   ID   COLS COLA
   AA    FI   YD
   AA    IN   YD
   AA    MH   YC
   AA    HI   YD
```

If the distinct of COLA is having any other value than YD, i should get the ID. What are the efficient Oracle - SQL query? Using group by & Having? or with over (partition by)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for `group by` and `having`.  One method is:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when cola <> 'YD' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

However, another approach might be:

```
select distinct id
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.cola <> 'YD');
```

Or:

```
select distinct id
from t
where cola <> 'YD;
```

It is hard to say which would be the fastest.  If you have a separate table of ids, then the best approach would be:

```
select ids.id
from ids
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = ids.id and t2.cola <> 'YD');
```

with an index on `t(id, cola)`.